# How can I prevent WinForms Chart from resizing as data is added?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I prevent a WinForms Chart object from autosizing on the X axis when a new tickmark comes up?

A picture, or in this case a gif, is worth a thousand words:

[image]

See the little jump when a new gridline, tick, and label show up? Super annoying.

I'm pretty sure that the setting is somewhere in `chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX` but I haven't been able to find anything that prevents this from happening.

Where should I look?

Comment: Read the TaWs answer, it will help you. Also you can try to fix `chart`1 size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding points at some point a new axis label must be added at each new interval. Since it is drawn **centered** at the value the chart needs to make room for it to **both** sides. The extra room to the right side then takes a while to be filled with data. This results in the jumps..

In my test the most straightforward solution was to simply **omit the last axis label**:

```
Axis ax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
ax.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = false;
```

[image]

Of course turning it back on when no more points are being added is a good idea.

Another, **much** more involved solution might be to disable the axis labels altogether and draw them in a `xxxPaint` event..

Comment: Awesome, that was what I was looking for! Thanks a bunch.